# How much usable storage space does the 16Gb Nexus 9 have?

Tags: rom, nexus-9

How much usable storage space is available on a 16Gb Nexus 9 once the space occupied by the OS, preinstalled software, etc. is subtracted?

Please do not answer with speculation; I am interested in answers with authoritative sources, or from people who have a Nexus 9 and can report directly.

To clarify: I am interested in the space available on a brand new Nexus 9, complete with everything that Google include on it. I remove it from the box, turn it on, and check the available storage. What do I see? :-)

Comment: There isn't a nexus-9 tag yet. Would anybody with rep like to create one? :-)

Comment: I've created nexus-9 tag. It will be active only after review of the moderators.

Comment: Are you talking about a stock Rom with all the bloatware or just a custom Rom that has been stripped down? They will have different sizes.

Comment: I'm interested in how much space is available if I take a new Nexus 9 out of the box, turn it on, and check. Thanks for pointing out ambiguity, I'll update the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the 16GB version: **11.05GB** [Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/Nexus9/comments/2l8863/just_picked_up_a_nexus_9_from_best_buy_ama/clsdt6l)

[image: Screenshot (taken from Reddit post)]

<sup>Click image for larger version</sup>

For the 32GB version: **25.61GB**

[image: Screenshot of 32GB version]

<sup>Click image for larger version</sup>